# Segmentation Fault in VSCode when Running very simple C++ Program with Vscode's cpptools extension

Tags: c++, mingw, segmentation-fault

I decided to ask this question here first, before seeking to open an issue on vscode-cpptools Github repository. Because you know, it's probably on my end either way and may be a very silly issue that someone has already gone through.

Here's a screenshot of the error:
[image]

Here's the #include error diagnosis in Vscode's:
[image]

---

### **Description of the Problem**

I've been encountering a persistent issue when attempting to run a simple C++ program using the vscode-cpptools extension in Visual Studio Code. Despite following recommended steps, I keep receiving a "segmentation fault" error, which appears out of place. The problem occurs on my notebook only, as I've successfully replicated the same environment on my desktop computer without any issues... Which is weird. Worth mentioning both machines have synchronized VSCode installations.

I've tried reinstalling mingw64 a couple times, and I use the ucrt64 environment as recommended by Visual Studio Code's "Get Started with C++ and MinGW-w64 in Visual Studio Code" tutorial.

I'm using g++ for compiling, which is correctly installed and operational in all my terminals.

I've experimented with [all three available options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONGed.png) for running the code, including "Run Code", but the segmentation fault error persists. When I choose the last option, "Run C/C++ File", a warning message appears, and then the segmentation fault error occurs as before.

[Here's the warning window I receive when I try to select the "Run C/C++ File" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJnMi.png)

---

### **Relevant GitHub Issue**

I discovered a [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7414) on the vscode-cpptools GitHub repository (Issue #7414), which includes a screenshot similar to my own. However, I didn't find any apparent connection between the two issues, and I don't have any breakpoints set in my editor.

---

### **Code Sample**

Here's the `hello_world.cpp` file in case someone wants to try reproducing the issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the `task.json` it generates when attempting to build the program:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

---

Again, this is very weird because I've reproduced the exact steps I've taken to install mingw and g++ in my desktop, but only the notebook has this problem.

Comment: Make sure that there are no other versions of the MinGW runtime in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Also see test if your program will run correctly directly from the `"C:\msys64\ucrt64.exe"` terminal.

Comment: I don't believe that the GitHub issue is related. I believe you have [Dll Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)

Comment: And it's s not just other mingw installs you have to worry about. Any folder in the system path holding the mingw library DLLs could be the villain. I've seen this with other tools built using mingw and even other programming languages that use libraries written in C++. The only good way to avoid DLL Hell is to be very careful about what you add to the system path. Sadly pretty much every <expletive deleted>ing Get Started With Tool X tutorial on the Internet says, "Add it to the path." Carnage ensues.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes, that seems to be the root cause of the issue. Turns out I initially deleted the entire 'msys64' folder from 'C:\' thinking it was enough to later do a fresh reinstall. However, I overlooked removing 'C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin' from the system's PATH. I thought it was unnecessary since I was reinstalling in the same directory. But it turned out that even after uninstalling all packages, I had to remove this specific entry from the PATH, then re-add it for everything to work smoothly.

Comment: Good you're back on your feet, but I strongly recommend not adding this to the path. Instead use build scripts and IDEs configured to use the full path to the build tools. Your world probably isn't as crazy as mine, but I've got half a dozen different versions of GCC running on my computer, needed for maintaining a variety of projects that I'm not allowed to simply unify and recompile with the most recent tools. Annoying as hell to have to use GCC3 alongside GCC13. But obviously I can't have all of them in the system path without regular, catastrophic explosions.